# Can I pass commands to Vimperator/Firefox through the command line?

Tags: firefox

For example, could I type something like

`firefox open` `this is a search`

where `open` is just passed to the vimperator command line?

Comment: Not sure about vimperator/pentadactyl options but if you want to open browser and pass string to default search engine you can do that: `$ firefox -search 'this is a search'`.

Comment: I asked this Q in the #vimperator IRC on freenode, nobody has responded thus far but I'll keep checking. I've also asked your Q on the Vimperator github project pg: https://github.com/vimperator/vimperator-labs/issues/48

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vimperator founder here:

Yes, it is possible. The complete syntax is here:
https://github.com/vimperator/vimperator-labs/blob/master/common/locale/en-US/starting.xml or given in `:help startup`

So try that:

```
firefox -vimperator "+c 'javascript alert(\"from commandline\");'"
```

would show an prompt after starting firefox. For opening URLs or searching, you need a slight "hack" as there is a race condition and we need to add a slight delay like so:

```
firefox -vimperator "+c \
    'javascript liberator.sleep(1000) && liberator.open(\"this is a search\");'"
```

If it is really required to put that content into the command line and not executing it directly, you can try the normal command:

```
firefox -vimperator "+c 'normal \":open this is a search\"'"
```

In general, pay attention about the correct escaping of quotes. I recommend using the mixture of " ' and \" like in the above examples.

#### Simplifying things

You can use the following function to make this a single one-liner, like so:

```
$ function vimpopen () {
    firefox -vimperator "+c 'normal \":open $@\"'"
}
```

Comment: I'm still a command line/linux newbie.  Is there something I  could type into my bashrc to simplify this to a single command, like "vimpopen 'here is a search'"?

Comment: @George - see the example at the end, LMK if that works for you.

Comment: Thanks for your respond(!), but it didn't work.  I changed it to the following:

function vimpopen() { firefox -vimperator "+c 'normal :open $@'"; }

And it sort of worked.  Firefox opens with what I type and I have to press enter.  The terminal is also linked to the firefox window so that if I close out of the terminal, then firefox also closes -- which isn't desirable.